# What is suggested method to get service versions

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine-python, app-engine-flexible

What is the best way to get list of service versions in google app engine in flex env? (from service instance in Python 3). I want to authenticate using service account json keys file. I need to find currently default version (with most of traffic).

Is there any lib I can use like `googleapiclient.discovery`, or `google.appengine.api.modules`? Or I should build it from scratches and request REST api on `apps.services.versions.list` using oauth? I couldn't not find any information in google docs..
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/python-differences#cloud_client_libraries

Answer (score 1):

Finally I was able to solve it. Simple things on GAE became big problems..

SOLUTION: 
I have path to service_account.json set in `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` env variable. Then you can use `google.auth.default`

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
import google.auth

creds, project = google.auth.default(scopes=['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform.read-only'])
service = build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=creds, cache_discovery=False)
data = service.apps().services().get(appsId=APPLICATION_ID, servicesId=SERVICE_ID).execute()
print data['split']['allocations']
```

Return value is allocations dictionary with versions as keys and traffic percents in values. 
All the best!

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google's [**Python Client Library**](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client) to interact with the Google App Engine **Admin API**, in order to get the list of a GAE service versions.

Once you have **google-api-python-client** installed, you might want to use the [**list**](http://googleapis.github.io/google-api-python-client/docs/dyn/appengine_v1beta5.apps.services.html#list) method to list all services in your application:

> list(appsId, pageSize=None, pageToken=None, x__xgafv=None)

The **arguments** of the method should include the following:

- **appsId**: *string*, Part of `name`. Name of the resource requested. Example: apps/myapp. (required)
- **pageSize**: *integer*, Maximum results to return per page.
- **pageToken**: *string*, Continuation token for fetching the next page of results.
- **x__xgafv**: *string*, V1 error format. Allowed **values**: *v1 error format*, *v2 error format*

You can find more information on this method in the link mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, yeah this is what I m trying to implement now. 

```service = build('appengine', 'v1', credentials=creds)```
```data = service.apps().services().get(appsId=APPLICATION_ID, name=SERVICE_ID).execute()```

Can I authenticate using service account json, with `InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file()`? Or there is easier option, maybe to make requests from gae instance I don't need to authenticate?